# How can I make the background dark while watching video?

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, video

While watching videos on my desktop(not in browser) I want to make the background dark.
For eg:

[image]

In the above pic I want everything to be black except the video. I don't want to make it full screen due to the reduction in the quality of the video.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this with the [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) media player:

1. Install  [vlc[image: Install vlc]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/vlc)
2. Load your video.
3. Uncheck *Video ➜ Scale*. This will keep the video the same size when viewed in fullscreen.
4. Hit <kbd>F11</kbd> to make VLC fullscreen.
5. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to hide the interface.

[image]

Comment: Viewer - you just got rick roll'd! And trolololol'd...

Answer (score 6):

This is actually not a solution but may I suggest you to use a more advanced player like VLC?

With VLC you can disable scaling with Video->Scale .

Comment: ... I was too late

Comment: I upvoted you :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably a nicer solution is the compiz-plugin `dim inactive` which once enabled will fade out all windows except the active one.

Ensure you have installed the package `compiz-plugins-extra`

To try it out, run `ccsm` (compiz-config-settings-manager) and

- enable *Dim Inactive* found in the Accessibility section
- Press `<super>p`

Answer (score 0):

For F11 to work, you will have to go to video tab and deselect always fit window.
Then you can select the video size.

Answer (score 0):

In VLC, go to VIDEO-->UNCHECK "ALWAYS FIT WINDOW" .

Now you can go full screen without the video being stretched.